# Android Things Raspberry pi 3 jack 3.5mm not working

Tags: pi-3, android-things

I implemented an application run on Raspberry Pi 3 using Android Things. This application will be able to play `rtsp` video and output to screen via HDMI port. But the audio is not working with jack 3.5mm. Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        videoView.setVideoPath("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov");
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

**How can I fix it?**

Comment: Is the audio currently being sent to the HDMI display?  In other OS's (Raspbian, etc.) you need to select to either send audio out the HDMI or the 3.5" stero jack.  Maybe look for a similar audio-output selection capability in Android Things?  I found a relevant (but not 100% same) answer  that might help you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035890/how-to-connect-speakers-for-android-things-without-hdmi

Comment: I had a similar issue with android things on a pi using the `android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech` library. Here is my [code](https://github.com/user-name-is-taken/autoCar/commit/dd323451711893444ebcc415c4212ea1905390da). I could only get audio to play out of the USB port. The mini RCA (headphone jack) and HDMI ports were silent.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if you connect the hdmi first, it will use the hdmi as the audio output.

Try connecting the audio jack first. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot get the 3.5" jack working, Android Things also supports USB audio as well.  A viable solution might be to just get a $7 USB audio card that has 3.5mm jacks on it, something like this:

[image: Generic USB audio card with 3.5mm jacks for speaker and microphone]

I found a good question/answer related to this in [another post HERE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66815/how-can-i-get-audio-ultrasonic-nearby-api-working-with-android-things).

Good Luck, and please write back here to let us know what you found!

Comment: OK I will try your solution. If I find some things I will let you know.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it seems not to be working out of the box. I suspect that following code should be implemented as part of Android Things audio management : https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/audio.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in `config.txt` file:

```
hdmi_ignore_edid_audio=1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While this might work, it might be beneficial to explain why. Also, if you would provide the qualified path of config.txt, it would probably help.